# Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\travel\resources\views\user\profile.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

before all that it was working perfectly fine but after i've updated the profile it began to show the error where there's only div present.[profile.blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0NV5.jpg)

and the error is [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vyYE.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
{{ $users->photo_id->file }}
```

you should probably use:

```
{{ $users->photo->file }}
```

PS. And next time please put code into question and not put links to screenshots only.

Comment: i'll make sure to put the code next time. :) thanks once again