# Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. (View

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm trying to get the properties from the array returned by get method of Eloquent. It is a nested array as you see in image

I have tried the following answers from stackoverflow.

[Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366092/property-title-does-not-exist-on-this-collection-instance) ,

[Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\travel\resources\views\user\profile.blade.php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673286/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-view-c-xampp-htdocs-travel-resources-vie)

[Looping PHP Nested Arrays - Extract values into Blade Views (Laravel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299204/looping-php-nested-arrays-extract-values-into-blade-views-laravel)

My blade code is

```
 @if(isset($reportRP))
 @foreach($reportRP as $rrp)
  <tr>
<td>{{ $rrp['name'] }}</td>
<td>{{$rrp['reports']->id }}</td>
 @endforeach
 @endif
```

[image: Collection returned by Eloquent get method]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe:

```
@if(isset($reportRP))
    @foreach($reportRP as $rrp)
       <tr>
       <td>{{ $rrp['name'] }}</td>
       @foreach($rrp['reports'] as $report)
           <td>{{ $report['id'] }}</td>
       @endforeach
        </tr>
     @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks, @blinkofaneye. Yeah, that's working. I'm showing it in a table where each patient name has report. If reports are multiple, the patient name will be repeated with each report. But this code shows all reports in same <td>.  Does it make sense?

Comment: You're welcome. That's wierd it should generate a <td> for each report xD

Comment: Thank I just figure it out from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`$rrp['reports']` is an array of items. You'll have to specify from which object you'll want the `id` property

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you can use Laravel function optional and if your object is empty it will return null

> $rrp['name']->name ----- Will return error if $rrp['name'] is null
>
> optional($rrp['name'])->name ----- Will return null if $rrp['name'] is null

Comment: Thanks, it is nice information but not the answer to my question. I just got the answer from @blinkofaneye.